# Issue with Predictive Text in Form Fields

Tags: android, web, autocomplete

I am having an issue in a credit card field on my website. When user is on Samsung device using Predictive Text, no numbers will enter into cc field text area unless user holds down the numbers for a second, long entry. When turning predictive text off on user side, it automatically fixes issue. Any suggestions on how to prevent predictive text from causing this issue on the web developer side?

Comment: Basically, predictive text is causing issue on my website's credit card field. All other fields, even number fields, are working correctly - but not the credit card field when user has predictive text turned on.